# How can I leverage AWS Lambda to read a file from S3 and write it to AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I want to read a csv file from S3 and write it to AWS EFS using AWS Lambda. How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Comment: It is not possible to mount an EFS to lambda function. 
Create an ec2 instance, mount EFS and download file will work.

Comment: Alternatively, I want to read a csv file from S3 and write it to AWS EFS in code pipeline. How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Comment: It is also not possible to mound efs to a lambda function. One possible solution is to place an Fargate task to copy file from s3 to efs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_efs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ECS / Fargate to read a file from S3 and write to EFS. For your case, you can create a lambda to run ECS Task which would read from S3 and write to EFS and have that triggered by S3.

Using Lambda alone you can't use EFS because to use EFS you would need to mount as a device, hence you would need either ECS or EC2. As of April 8, 2020, ECS and Fargate support EFS generally available [[Link]](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-ecs-aws-fargate-support-amazon-efs-filesystems-generally-available/).

Comment: What about AWS DataSync? How does that compare with running an ECS task. BTW, you can trigger ECS directly from S3 through CloudTrail events

Comment: Lambda now supports EFS: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/aws-lambda-support-for-amazon-elastic-file-system-now-generally-/